# localStorage.removeItem() not removing key/value from object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, local-storage, web-storage

Struggling to figure this one out...

I'm trying to remove a key/value pair, from my localStorage object.  However, nothing gets removed.  (I also don't have any errors).

I understand I can remove the key/value in question, by it's key name.  Here's an example of the object:

```
   bookMarksArray:    [
        {
            "name": "reena",
            "url": "brian"
        },
        {
            "name": "joe",
            "url": "ault"
        }
       ]
```

And here's my code... I'm  using event target to grab and match the key name, to the object index.

And then passing in key of that object index, into **localStorage.removeItem()**... What am I doing wrong?

```
  list.addEventListener('click', event => {
    if (event.target.classList.contains('js-delete-url')) {

      const editName = event.target.parentElement.name.value;
      const objIndex = bookMarksArray.findIndex(obj => obj.name === editName);

      localStorage.removeItem(bookMarksArray[objIndex].name);
      console.log('delete', bookMarksArray[objIndex].name);
    }
  });
```

Console prints this:

> app.js:55 delete reena

Thank you!

Comment: You can not remove specific array item (because it store as a string), get whole array into a javascript variable then delete the item and again push updated variable to localstorage.

Comment: Does the console statement printing the exact name you want to remove?

Comment: I believe there is some misunderstanding here. `localStorage` storages a **string**, not an object. Do you want to remove the key/value pair from the object, or do you want to remove a particular `localStorage` key?

Comment: Hi @GangadharGandi - Yes it returns this:

delete
app.js:52 objIndex 0
app.js:54 removeObj.name) reena
app.js:55 delete reena

Comment: @GerardoFurtado - So I'd like to remove an entire key/value.   Like name: Joe, url: ault - thank you

Comment: Further to the comments above, this line: `localStorage.removeItem(bookMarksArray[objIndex].name);` is equivalent to `localStorage.removeItem("reena");` which wouldn't work even if localStorage worked the way you think it does.

Comment: @Moob - Doesn't it look for keyname?  localStorage.removeItem(keyname)

Comment: Well, the problems seems to be a misunderstanding regarding how `localStorage` works. `localStorage` will storage your data (whatever it is) as a **string**, with another string as the key. For instance, `localStorage.setItem("foo", "datastring")`. Both key and value are strings. Then, if you do `localStorage.removeItem("foo")`, you remove that particular data string associated with that key. That's all.

Comment: "reena" isn't the key name "name" is. localStorage will store string key value pairs. if you need to store an object you would have to stringify it (eg: localStorage.setItem("things", JSON.stringify(things));) See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/removeItem.

Comment: Yes of course, sorry brain mush.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado - ok thanks Gerado, so basically I can't use this.  I just need to delete an item from the array and update the localStorage again?

Comment: @ReenaVerma you don't even need to delete it. Just use `setItem` with the same key to overwrite the old data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LocalStoage saves the value in string format, so you have to stringify JSON object every time to save it in localStorage, we can solve this problem, please find below code snippet, useful in this scenario,

```js
var updateStorage = function(filterName) {
 var bookMarksArray=   [{"name": "reena", "url": "brian"}, {"name": "joe", "url": "ault"}]
 localStorage.setItem('nameList', JSON.stringify(bookMarksArray));
      var items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('nameList'));
 var updatedList = items.filter(function(a) {
          return a.name !== filterName;
      });
 localStorage.setItem('nameList', JSON.stringify(updatedList));
 console.log(localStorage.getItem('nameList'));
    // result [{"name":"reena","url":"brian"}]
};
updateStorage('joe');
```

Comment: Hi Both - Sarvesh/OutofWorld = these worked perfectly, thank you so much.  I made an error, not realising first this was a string, so not editable. But also, I had to manipulate the array. Thank you so much guys!

Answer (score 0):

```
//set js object to localstorage
localStorage.setItem('bookMarksArray',JSON.stringify(bookMarksArray))

//get js object from localstorage
bookMarksArray= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bookMarksArray'))

//remove desired item
bookMarksArray = bookMarksArray.filter(function(item) {
    return item.name !== 'reena';
});

//update js object in localstorage
localStorage.setItem('bookMarksArray',JSON.stringify(bookMarksArray))
```

Comment: Please don't copy code from the same answer.
Please maintain the integrity of this portal

Comment: sorry dude but i did not copy your code. Just check my comments on the question about the procedure.